Your friendly reminder to vote (!)
I'm not meaning to nag here, but I thought I might remind/encourage everyone to vote.  Vote Early, Vote Often.  Oh, and thank you to those who are voting!
Everyone has their own voting philosophy; I'm more on the generous side (after all, reputation is just "internet points", and it's a way of saying thank you for contributing), while others tend to downvote more, which is great for quality control.
However...

I sometimes see questions with comments and 3+ answers and no votes anywhere... something's not right there.

Often it feels getting on the hot network question list is make-or-break for voting: users from other sites come here and vote like mad.


Be aware that...

Reputation grants privileges and other features (e.g. a gold tag badge allows users to unilaterally close questions with that tag), and we need users to use these tools (especially voting to close; currently requires 500 rep).

Upvoting encourages similar content.  Downvoting discourages it.  Either way, voting greatly affects what content we get, and how much we get.


(Plus other things I've probably forgotten to mention.)

By the way, perhaps you can find interesting content via the Greatest Hits page, or even random questions via DiceStack.  Another option is the One Vote Short Data Explorer query, which finds posts one vote away from earning a badge.
